# Self referencing SQL query with One To Many Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient query I can write with dapper to accomplish the following:

I have a normalized database with orders and lineitems with a one-to-many relationship.

I have to find lineitems where the sale price is greater than or equal to a "ThresholdValue" in it's order. ThresholdValue can vary with each order.

If threshold value was a constant, it would be a simple query. I'm thinking that I have to Select all the invoices to collect the threshold values and then loop through those invoices with their values to select the line items.

Is there a more efficient SQL query to accomplish this? If so, is there a name for this type of query?

Sample Data

Orders

```
| id | threshold |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | 1000     |
| 2   | 2000     |

LineItems

| OrderId | SalePrice |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | 500   |
| 1   | 2000  |
| 2   | 2500  |
| 2   | 1500  |


Expected result is

| OrderId | SalePrice |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | 2000  |
| 2   | 2500  |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to add something like `AND lineitems.saleprice >= orders.ThresholdValue` to your `JOIN` condition

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample data added. btw, table markdown is not working so it's in code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN`:

```
select l.*
from orders o join
     lineitems l
     on l.orderid = l.id
where l.saleprice > o.threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want to filter out the one that are less than threshold :

```
select * from LineItems l
where SalePrice >  ( select threshold from Orders o where l.OrderId = o.OrderId)
```